# How to specify multiple "env_files" for a docker compose service?

Tags: docker-compose

Currently I have setup my service like the following.

```
version: '3'
services:
  gateway:
    container_name: gateway
    image: node:lts-alpine
    working_dir: /
    volumes:
      - ./package.json:/package.json
      - ./tsconfig.json:/tsconfig.json
      - ./services/gateway:/services/gateway
      - ./packages:/packages
      - ./node_modules:/node_modules
    env_file: .env
    command: yarn run ts-node-dev services/gateway --colors
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
```

So I have specified one `env_file`. But now I want to pass multiple .env files.

Unfortunately, the following is not possible:

```
    env_files:
       - .env.secrets
       - .env.development
```

Is there any way to pass multiple .env files to one service in docker-compsoe?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can specify multiple env files on the `env_file` option (without `s`).

For instance:

```
version: '3'

services:
  hello:
    image: alpine
    entrypoint: ["sh"]
    command: ["-c", "env"]
    env_file:
      - a.env
      - b.env
```

Comment: It appears that using this method the key/values from the .env cannot be accessed inside of the docker-compose.yaml like the can when using the CLI `--env-file <path to .env>` if using `docker compose up`. https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/ Hope that saves someone time.

Comment: @Hunter but i seem able to reference if the name is `.env` only

Answer (score 11):

Note that, complementary to @conradkleineespel's answer, if an environment variable is defined in multiple .env files listed under `env_file`, the value found in the last environment file in the list overwrites all prior (tested in a docker-compose file with `version: '3.7'`.

Comment: Have you found any docs to substantiate this? This doesn't happen in my experience. Docker seems to somehow 'prefer' certain env files when deciding precedence where multiple env files contain the same var. There doesn't seem to be a reliable way to control which env file ultimately contributes the value.

Comment: @Mitya Yes, it is clearly stated in the official docs here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#env_file

"Keep in mind that the order of files in the list is significant in determining the value assigned to a variable that shows up more than once. The files in the list are processed from the top down. For the same variable specified in file a.env and assigned a different value in file b.env, if b.env is listed below (after), then the value from b.env stands."

Answer (score 8):

Starting from version 2.17.0 (right now it is [rc.1](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/tag/v2.17.0-rc.1), but will be 2.17.0 soon) you can specify multiple files as cli params: `sudo docker compose --env-file .env --env-file dev.env up`

Pros:

1. You can access key/values inside the docker-compose.yaml.
2. You don't need to duplicate `env_file` section in multiple services.

Cons:

1. More characters in command.
2. When you invoke commands like `sudo docker compose logs` you will need to specify  `--env-file .env --env-file dev.env`. Otherwise you will see errors like `WARN[0000] The "VAR_NAME" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string`.

Comment: interesting..does the second override variables in the first?

Comment: are the cons is still valid for docker-compose version 3.8 ?

Comment: @n79qk272x57w46w9, don't know for sure because haven't test it.